# How to include template members in collaboration graph?

Tags: c++, doxygen

When I'm trying to generate a collaboration graph for classes including container members, like vectors, Doxygen does not notice that it has documentation on that class. Maybe an example will show what I mean:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
    int number;
};

class Bar
{
    int anotherNumber;
};

class MyClass
{
    Bar x;
    std::vector<Foo> y;
};
```

But the collaboration graph does not contain information about `Foo`, even though it is part of the project.

[image]

If you want to try it yourself, set

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
```

Is there any way to include `Foo` properly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. Doxygen does not compile your code, so any functions you call don't matter.

Comment: What do you mean with "Doxygen does not notice that it has documentation on that class"? Do you expect it to create a link to `Foo` class in the collaboration graph? You can always add a reference to `Foo` manually in the documentation of `MyClass`.

Comment: Well, it creates a link for `Bar`, and tells me that `Bar` has a member `anotherNumber`. Why should it not tell me that `Foo` also has another member? In cases where you have multiple container members of various classes, it "hides" the interdependencies between these classes, because you can't immediately see what they in turn contain, as you do with "normal" (`Bar`-like) members.